# Use .NetCore class library on windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to create a windows service that reuses the classes that I have created on .NETCore class libraries. I have a sample project.json from one of my .NETCore class libraries as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net451+win8" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have been following this approach http://taskmatics.com/blog/run-dnx-applications-windows-service/. I have created a console application and changed its project.json file as indicated. However, whenever I try to declare my other class libraries as a dependency I get an error indicating

> 'The dependency could not be resolved'

This is the project.json file that I am using for my windows service application:

```
 {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    //"MyClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*",
    //When uncommenting everything fails
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceProcess": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way that I can use .NETCore classes for my service?

Comment: "...try to declare my other class libraries as a dependency..." - Are these also .Net Core libraries, or full .Net Framework libraries?

Comment: Please stop using the "dnx" tag, as the concept is now obsolete.

Comment: @WillRay these are .net core libraries

Comment: @Luis Becerril did you found any solution ?

Comment: yes @elhampour the solution is marked as an answer

Comment: @LuisBecerril the solution is for using net451 framework . my class library which windows service is using is .netcore framework and i cant change it because whole application depends on it , so i need a solution for .netcore framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `netcoreapp1.0` framework in the class library is not compatible with the `dnx451` framework in your console application. Replacing both with `net451` should work *in this particular case*.

#### Console App

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "MyClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
  }

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.ServiceProcess": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Your Class Libraries

**Note:** You can remove the `netcoreapp1.0` and `dependencies` nodes if this doesn't need to be a NetStandard library.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net451+win8" ]
    },
    "net451": { }
  }
}
```

The tutorial you are following is quite old. `dnx` [is now obsolete](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/README.md) and has been replaced with the new .Net CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! That's because NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 doesn't support 4.5.1, it only supports 4.6.3+ (of the .NET Framework)

Your class library need to down to .netstandard 1.2. More details, you can see at [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms)